# C#, Ajax Redirection to another page through static method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have and ajax and C# method ...

I need to redirect to another page in the static web method..

But I am unable to do so.

methods for redirection to another page are follwoing

```
 if (tempUser == "0")
                {

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("list.aspx");
                }
```

**AJAX**

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {
                    var HTML = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
                //  alert(HTML);
                var Fname = document.getElementById("MyText").value;
                Senddata = { "HTML": HTML, "Fname": Fname };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "/wwwroot/Default.aspx/save",
                    data: JSON.stringify(Senddata),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {


                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**C# STATIC WEB METHOD**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void save(string HTML, string Fname)
    {


        HttpContext.Current.Session["GUID"] = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MS"].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            string tempUser = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempUser))
            {
                tempUser = "0";
            }

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Forms(Name,HTML,UserID,GUID)values(@Name,@HTML,@UserID,@GUID)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1024).Value = Fname;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@HTML", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000).Value = HTML.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tempUser;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@GUID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = HttpContext.Current.Session["GUID"];

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            if (tempUser == "0")
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("list.aspx");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            CommonBLL.WriteExceptionLog(ex, "Form Save Default.aspx");
            throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```

error thrown in catch block is

```
[System.Threading.ThreadAbortException] = {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot redirect from server side code during or after an ajax call.
At least you could return a url (Eg. Response.write("YourURlBuildOnC#")) to use for redirect on the success function

Comment: yes , you are ccorrect.. i solved my question by changing static string and return valuue  to the ajax succeess function

Answer (score 1):

You have to redirect in the SUCCESS function of the ajax call:

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {
    var HTML = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
    //  alert(HTML);
    var Fname = document.getElementById("MyText").value;
    Senddata = { "HTML": HTML, "Fname": Fname };
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
            url: "/wwwroot/Default.aspx/save",
            data: JSON.stringify(Senddata),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

HOPE this helps`enter code here`